# Inequality with complex root and positive imaginary part

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality, complex-numbers

Let $z$ be a complex number with $\mathrm{Im}(z)>0$, and we consider
$$w:=\frac{-z+\sqrt{z^2-4}}{2}.$$
It is written that "we take the square root so that $\mathrm{Im}(w)>0".$
I want to prove that such a square root exists. My first try was to define
$$\sqrt{z}:=\frac{\mathrm{sign}(\mathrm{Im}(z))\sqrt{|z|+\mathrm{Re}(z)}+\mathrm{i}\sqrt{|z|-\mathrm{Re}(z)}}{\sqrt{2}},$$
so that we always have $\mathrm{Im}(\sqrt{z^2-4})>0,$ which is a necessary condition since we assumed $\mathrm{Im}(z)>0$. However, I was not able to obtain 
$$\mathrm{Im}(\sqrt{z^2-4})>\mathrm{Im}(z).$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $z\not\in\mathbb{R}$, we know $z^2-4\ne 0$ and thus has two square roots $z_1$ and $z_2$, with $z_1+z_2=0$. If we let $w_1 = \frac{-z+z_1}{2}$ and $w_2 = \frac{-z+z_2}{2}$, then it's easy to check that $w_1+w_2 = -z$ and $w_1w_2 = 1$. We know $w_1$ and $w_2$ cannot both be real, as their sum is not real, so suppose $\text{Im}(w_1)\ne 0$. If $\text{Im}(w_1) > 0$, then we're done; otherwise $\text{Im}(w_1)<0$, and $\text{Im}(w_2) = \text{Im}\left(\frac{1}{w_1}\right) > 0$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Let $z = x + iy$, then since $\Im(z^2 - 4) = \Im(x^2 - y^2 - 4 + 2xiy) =  2xy$, we then have $\Im(z^2 - 4) > \Im(z) \iff 2xy > y \iff y(2x-1) > 0$.

Comment: I forgot the square root in the last inequality LHS, so that I need a bit more than this.